# Dynamic Settings in ConEmu

Tags: conemu

I run ConEmu in portable mode (via Dropbox folder) and I absolutely love it.

I was wondering if I could have certain settings change based upon which computer I am running ConEmu on.

For example, on my MacBook Pro Retina, I have to up the ConEmu fontsize to about 36 so I can see it correctly.  However, when running ConEmu on my office computer I need the font size to stay at around 18.

Any idea on how I might be able to accomplish this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may read about ConEmu command line switches in the "About" dialog (system menu -> About -> Help/About) or in then project [wiki](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/Command_Line).

[image]

So, you may use environment variables for switching configuration, for example using named configuration

```
ConEmu /config "%COMPUTERNAME%"
```

or using different xml files:

```
ConEmu /loadcfgfile "ConEmu-%COMPUTERNAME%.xml"
```

You may create shortcut for that commands on your desktop. Or, even create shortcut in your dropbox folder, but there is a trick to allow using relative paths: `cmd /c ConEmu /config "%ComputerName%"`

[image]